# Derivative of solutions of equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I have a series of measurements $y_i$ at time points $x_i$ and want to fit a function $f(x)=y$ to my data. The function is a polynomial plus a damped cosine:
$$
f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^Na_ix^i + A\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x}\cos(\phi x + \theta)
$$
To fit the function, I minimize as objective function the sum of squared residuals:
$$
\Omega(a_i, A, \alpha, \phi, \theta) = \sum\limits_i (f(x_i)-y_i)^2
$$
The parameters $a_i$, $A$ and $\theta$ can be determined by a linear equation system setting their derivatives to zero (shown here for N=2):
$$
A=\left|\begin{array}{cccccc} 
\sum\limits_ix_i^2 & \sum\limits_ix_i  & \sum\limits_ix_i  \mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\cos\phi x_i & \sum\limits_ix  \mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\sin\phi x_i \\ 
%
\sum\limits_ix_i  & \sum\limits_i1   &    \sum\limits_i\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\cos\phi x_i &    \sum\limits_i\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\sin\phi x_i \\
% 
\sum\limits_ix_i\cos\phi x_i & \sum\limits_i\cos\phi x_i & \sum\limits_i\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\cos^2\phi x_i & \sum\limits_i\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\sin\phi x_i\cos\phi x_i \\
% 
\sum\limits_ix_i\sin\phi x_i & \sum\limits_i\sin\phi x_i & \sum\limits_i\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\sin\phi x_i\cos\phi x_i & \sum\limits_i\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\sin^2\phi x_i \\
\end{array}\right|
$$
$$
b=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\sum\limits_ix_i  y_i\\
\sum\limits_i     y_i\\
\sum\limits_i\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\cos\phi x_i\\
\sum\limits_i\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x_i}\sin\phi x_i
\end{array}
\right)
$$
To find the parameters $\alpha$ and $\phi$, I would use nonlinear optimization routines. But to do that, I need the derivatives of $\Omega$ by $\alpha$ and $\phi$. To calculate this, I first need the derivatives of $a_i$, $A$, and $\theta$ ba $\alpha$ and $\phi$ - what leads me to the question of the derivatives of solutions of linear equation systems.
I read about Jacobi's formula to calculate the derivative of a determinant using adjoint matrices, but that seems computationally intensive because I have to calculate all cofactors.
Any hint to a possibility to calculate these derivatives is highly welcome!

Comment: Please be detailed in your post (what eq. you are talking about,what is your understanding of it, what you have tried doing, etc.)